# How to access JSON data in script tag using jQuery in a bookmarklet

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, bookmarklet

I'm writing a bookmarklet that injects jQuery and then tries to access certain data on a webpage. The page uses AngularJS. The JSON data I want can be seen in a script tag when clicking view source in Chrome.

```
<script type="text/json" class="menu-page-data" page="0">
    /* The JSON data */
</script>
```

I'm unable to access this data though with `JSON.parse($('.menu-page-data').html())`.

How can a bookmarklet parse this JSON?

Comment: if the codebehind is removing it, it can't. also, `$('.menu-page-data')` doesn't return null, or you're failing to include jquery.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, you're right. I corrected my questions regarding `null`.

Comment: inspect element and see if it is still part of the dom after the page loads. My guess is it isn't. If it isn't, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: @KevinB I'm unable to inspect element since this data is in a script tag and only shows up on the page after clicking a button. I'm confused as to why something that shows up in View Source is inaccessible to a bookmarklet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by @DG., the following code works to get the text inside the `<script>` tag and parse it as JSON.

```
$.get(document.location.href).done(function (htmlText) {
    var scriptClassIndex = htmlText.indexOf('menu-page-data');
    var scriptSubStr = htmlText.substring(scriptClassIndex);
    var scriptEndIndex = scriptSubStr.indexOf('</script>');

    var justScript = scriptSubStr.substring(0, scriptEndIndex);
    justScript = justScript.replace('menu-page-data" page="0">', '');
    justScript = justScript.trim();
    var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(justScript);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `console.log($('.menu-page-data').html())` show the JSON data? If yes, then the problem is not in the access, it's in the parsing.

If no, then perhaps the script is being removed from the DOM before you run your bookmarklet. You say that you can see the script tag and JSON data when you "View Source". The HTML source and the DOM are not the same. The source is used to create the DOM when the page loads, but the DOM can change from that point on.

One possible way to access the original source code is with an AJAX call. Then you can do a bit of string manipulation to pull out the JSON data. It's not pretty, but it can work. It might look something like this: `$.ajax(document.location.href).done(function(htmltext){ /*string manipulation*/ });`

Comment: `$.ajax(document.location.href).done(function (htmltext) {console.log($('.menu-page-data').html()); });` shows `undefined`. Simply trying to `console.log` the data also doesn't work.

Comment: If that short code you wrote could work, I would have put it into my answer from the start. Unfortunately, the errors in that code indicates that you are probably attempting to program at a level too far above your current understanding. It indicates a lack of understanding of some critical core concepts.